# How do I assign value to a row in a dataframe based on another in r?

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, data-manipulation

I am looking at data on butterflies that have been caught in different samples.My problem is that there has been inconsistency in the 'names' (numbers) used for the same species. The species have each been assigned a number to identify them.

I have two dataframes, the first is a dataset of counts of each species "**mydata**" but each species in it has been assigned multiple IDs, instead of just one correct one. So two different numbers may refer to the same species, and I need to make sure my names are standardised.

```
IDs <- c(10,8,3,42,7,23,42,2)
sample1 <- c(0,0,2,0,3,0,0,2)
sample2 <- c(0,1,0,2,4,0,3,1)
sample3 <- c(0,1,1,0,2,0,3,1)
sample4 <- c(0,2,0,2,0,1,2,1)
sample5 <- c(3,1,0,0,1,0,0,1)
mydata <- cbind(IDs,sample1,sample2,sample3,sample4,sample5)
```

I have a second database that I am using as a reference, "**specieslist**", and this contains the correct ID, plus all alternative IDs that may have been used.

```
ID1 <- c(10,34,20,2,7,38)
ID2 <- c(22,3,42,NA,6,23)
ID3 <- c(NA,8,NA,NA,1,NA)
correct.ID <- c(10,3,20,2,1,23)
specieslist <- cbind(ID1,ID2,ID3,correct.ID)
splist <- replace(specieslist,is.na(specieslist),0)
```

I want to search **specieslist** to find out which number should be used in
**mydata**, and assign the correct ID to a new column in **mydata**.

I have been trying to create a loop that will find out which row of **specieslist** contains the value in **mydata**, and then selecting the value in the **correctID** column for that row.

```
corr.sp <- c(NULL)
rws <- length(mydata[,1])
for(s in 1:rws){
  dat <- as.character(mydata[s,1])
  pos <- which(splist==dat, arr.ind=TRUE)
  ind <- pos[1,1]
  corr <- as.matrix(splist[ind,4])
  corr.sp <- c(corr.sp,corr)
}

mydata.corrsps <- cbind(mydata,corr.sp)
```

What I expect is for **corr.sp** and **mydata.corrsps** to look like this:

```
corr.sp <- c(10,3,3,20,1,23,20,2)
mydata.corrsps <- cbind(mydata,corr.sp)
```

This demo code seems to work, but in some of my real data my an error appears when I run the loop saying my row index (**pos[1,1]**) is out of bounds  - I've had this error before when it searches for rows of species that weren't found in that dataset, but I have been through and removed any rows where this applies, saved the file as a csv and reimported it to avoid errors of row-index mix-ups (seems to happen with data when subsetting in r). I have also checked that the maximum value for the **pos(1,1)** does not exceed the number of rows available for selection, and I have checked that all values it searches for are present in the data.

I would be very grateful if anyone could suggest a better way of doing what I am unsuccessfully trying to do, or point out where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make `splist` long format, and then merge the relevant columns with `mydata`:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

# splist to long format
long.splist <- data.frame(splist) %>% gather(key, IDs, ID1:ID3)

# merge
merge(mydata,long.splist[,c(3,1)])
#  IDs sample1 sample2 sample3 sample4 sample5 correct.ID
#1   2       2       1       1       1       1          2
#2   3       2       0       1       0       0          3
#3   7       3       4       2       0       1          1
#4   8       0       1       1       2       1          3
#5  10       0       0       0       0       3         10
#6  23       0       0       0       1       0         23
#7  42       0       2       0       2       0         20
#8  42       0       3       3       2       0         20
```

The result is ordered by `IDs`, as that's the column on which the join was performed.

Comment: Sorry for not replying faster - this is a much better approach! I'd been trying to figure out how to do it in sql with multiple columns as keys, but have almost no familiarity with that environment. This achieves just what I want, thanks!